# Backing up Entire Ubuntu System to External Hard Drive with Windows Partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows, backup

I just used the windows backup utility to store a bootable image (I think..) to a 1TB external hard drive.

Do I have to store the Ubuntu partition (backup) to a different sub directory in the hard drive, or will the computer read both of the partitions in GRUB even if they are stored in the same directory? (Like, the series of files stored when one backs up).

Also, how do I backup my entire Ubuntu partition (including GRUB bootloader) to said external hard drive?

Thank you very much!

I realize these are multiple questions, but they are rather related, so I decided to use a single thread.

Comment: What do you mean “store the […] partition to a […] subdirectory”?

Comment: I already have the files for a windows boot disk inside the hard drive (or at least I think I do. Not really too sure how the windows backup system works). I'm asking if the Ubuntu boot disk (backup) files will interfere with the Windows files if they share the same disk, and vice versa.

Comment: What backup files are you talking about? How did you create these backups? There are myriads of possible ways.